# Regex not matching? Encoding the issue?

Tags: php, regex, encoding, utf-8

Weird problem...

I have this document, when I copy the text and place it inside my script (as a string variable), the regex matches successfully. However, when I use file_get_contents to get to the document (from the internet), it does not.

Does this have something to do with encoding? The document is ISO-8859-1, but converted to utf8 via utf8_encode

Note that the string variable is created from this utf8 encoded output.

It's a simple regex too:

```
if (preg_match_all('/<h3 align=center><A NAME="([^"]*)"><\/A>(.*)<\/h3>(.*)::break::/isUu', $contents, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Do a var_dump of your copy/paste variable and then then the content from file_get_contents to check if there is any difference.

Comment: Open file with browser/wget and look at its encoding. Maybe, it is returned in `utf-8`, but you save it manually in `iso-latin-1`

Answer (score 0):

This was not due to encoding, but due to the backtrack_limit being reached.

Overriding the setting with the following:

```
 ini_set('pcre.backtrack_limit', '1000000');
```

(up from 100,000) fixes the issue. PHP 5.3.? also has this value so it's not just some really large number.